# Efficient management of instances with unique dictionaries in a repeated instantiation situation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, multiple-instances

About my problem:

I create instances of a class several times, each time my frontend sends a message to my backend.(This can't be changed either).

Now the instances have to fulfill the following:

1. The dictionary must not be lost each time the instance is created.
2. The instances have different dictionaries.

Do you know how I can realize this?

Until now I have this in my class:

```
class ScheduleOptimizeNew:
    data = {
        "Station": {
        }}
    def __init__(self, cfgpath):
        self.cfg = cfgpath
```

and here its get created in my app.py:

```
scheduleroptimizernew= ScheduleOptimizeNew(CFGPath)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean `instance1.data` and `instance2.data` must not be the same? If so you have to move the `data = {}` to the inside of `__init__`

Comment: Yes i mean it. But if i do so, the data gets deleted everytime i create the instances.

Comment: What data? why do you want to share and not share at the same time? Could you post an example? like "I create this instance and this is the value, I create this other instance and this is the value, and then I do this and this are the new values or the values still"

Comment: Ok then for further understanding: 
The program is a simulation. I run several simulations independently at the same time. During the simulation, data is generated and added to the data. Since the simulations are independent, they have different independent data. The data is now added to the above instance to the Data dictionary.

Comment: You said "the data gets deleted everytime i create the instances", based on you last message you don't want to share the `data` property value between instances, right?

Comment: yes i dont want to share them between the instances. The instances are completly independet, its a completely different simulation with other parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255609/discussion-between-meno-and-daviid).

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code so you can understand Class Variables vs Instance Variables:

### Class Variables

```py
class ScheduleOptimizeNew:
    data = "Shared between instances"
    def __init__(self):
        pass

instance1 = ScheduleOptimizeNew()
instance2 = ScheduleOptimizeNew()
instance3 = ScheduleOptimizeNew()

print("\n------------------")
print("Original")
print(instance1.data)
print(instance2.data)
print(instance3.data)
print("------------------")

instance2.data = "Modified value"

print("\n------------------")
print("Modified through instance")
print(instance1.data)
print(instance2.data)
print(instance3.data)
print("------------------")


ScheduleOptimizeNew.data = "Modified value"


print("\n------------------")
print("Modified through class")
print(instance1.data)
print(instance2.data)
print(instance3.data)
print("------------------")
```

Output:

```
------------------
Original
Shared between instances
Shared between instances
Shared between instances
------------------

------------------
Modified through instance
Shared between instances
Modified value
Shared between instances
------------------

------------------
Modified through class
Modified value
Modified value
Modified value
------------------
```

### Instance Variables

```py
class ScheduleOptimizeNew:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = "Specific to each instance"
        pass

instance1 = ScheduleOptimizeNew()
instance2 = ScheduleOptimizeNew()
instance3 = ScheduleOptimizeNew()

print("\n------------------")
print("Original")
print(instance1.data)
print(instance2.data)
print(instance3.data)
print("------------------")

instance2.data = "Modified value"

print("\n------------------")
print("Modified through instance")
print(instance1.data)
print(instance2.data)
print(instance3.data)
print("------------------")


ScheduleOptimizeNew.data = "Modified value"


print("\n------------------")
print("Modified through class")
print(instance1.data)
print(instance2.data)
print(instance3.data)
print("------------------")
```

Output

```
------------------
Original
Specific to each instance
Specific to each instance
Specific to each instance
------------------

------------------
Modified through instance
Specific to each instance
Modified value
Specific to each instance
------------------

------------------
Modified through class
Specific to each instance
Modified value
Specific to each instance
------------------
```